# Magento Commerce (Enterprise) 2.4 Rewards exclude category when Redeeming

Tags: magento, module, e-commerce, magento2, magento2.4

The enterprise version of magento includes an integrated reward points module. How do I modify this module to allow points redemption only for products in a specific category (or, another way of phrasing this question is, how do I exclude products in specific categories when redeeming points to pay during checkout)?

Comment: Hi Richard. Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi @GerarddeVisser, thank you for your answer. I am attempting to redeem / spend points on products in a specific category during the checkout, whereas your answer relates to acquiring / adding points. Do you happen to know how to redeem points in this fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use price rules to add reward points based on conditions. So this makes it possible to add reward points based on specific categories.

Please refer to: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/reward-points-price-rules.html